# PostgreSQL-specific error with reports_as_sparkline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm having trouble getting the [reports_as_sparkline plugin](http://github.com/marcoow/reports_as_sparkline) working on PostgreSQL (it works fine on SQLite).

Here's an example error:

```
>> Annotation.creations_report
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  operator does not exist: ` character varying
LINE 1: ... grouping = E'day' AND aggregation = E'count' AND `condition...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
: SELECT * FROM "reports_as_sparkline_cache" WHERE (model_name = E'Annotation' AND report_name = E'creations' AND grouping = E'day' AND aggregation = E'count' AND `condition` = E'' AND reporting_period >= '2009-11-22')  ORDER BY reporting_period ASC LIMIT 100
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop the backticks `, use single quotes '. In SQL only single and double quotes are allowd, single quotes for values, double quotes for database objects like table names, column names, etc.

```
SELECT * FROM "reports_as_sparkline_cache" WHERE (model_name = E'Annotation' AND report_name = E'creations' AND grouping = E'day' AND aggregation = E'count' AND condition = E'' AND reporting_period >= '2009-11-22')  ORDER BY reporting_period ASC LIMIT 100
```